# Composite key in SQL is one to many and not many to one right?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, one-to-many, composite-key

If I create a table with a composite key(One to many relationships). How do I ensure that the one-to-many relationship is one sided? What I mean is A and B are composite keys; A can have multiple B's, But B cannot have Multiple A's

**Edit:** Changed the data type from numeric to int

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE voting (
TaskOrder int,
MemberID int,
PRIMARY KEY (TaskOrder , MemberID)
);
```

Functional requirement - One Member can have multiple task orders. But one task order cannot be assigned to multiple Members.

How do I make sure? At first, I thought of using a composite key. Is there any other alternative? or using a composite key is ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `B` can not have multiple `A`, that makes `B` unique. `B` would be your primary key.

```
create table voting (
    TaskOrder int
  , MemberID int
  , primary key (TaskOrder)
 );
```

Unless you have some reason to use an unspecified `numeric`, just use `int`.

Comment: One taskOrder cannot have multiple memberIDs

Comment: @shockwave That is what my answer reflects, yes. Here is a rextester demo to illustrate: http://rextester.com/GJRV65698